# laravelの指定バージョンのインストールに失敗する

Tags: laravel, composer

laragonを利用して、ローカル環境でLaravelを動作させたいと考えています。
本番のLaravelにあわせてバージョンを指定した上でインストールしたいのですが
バージョンを指定すると「Could not find package」と表示されてインストールに失敗します。
これは何が原因でしょうか。

PHPバージョンは 8.1.0 です。

こちらがエラーがでるコードです。

```
composer create-project "laravel/laravel=9.20.0" %s --prefer-dist
```

下記のようなエラーが表示されます。

```
In CreateProjectCommand.php line 438:
Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 9.20.0.
```

こちらは問題なくインストールされます。

```
composer create-project "laravel/laravel=9.*" %s --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score 0):

自分の環境でも同様でした。
最新で入るのが9.3.8なので、それ以前のバージョンなら指定できそうですね。

```
$ composer create-project "laravel/laravel=9.*" %s --prefer-dist
Creating a "laravel/laravel=9.*" project at "./%s"
Installing laravel/laravel (v9.3.8)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v9.3.8): Extracting archive
```

ChangeLogでは確かに9.32.0まで出てますが
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/CHANGELOG.md

composerに対応バージョンの遅れがあるとか？

```
$ composer create-project "laravel/laravel=9.3.7" %s --prefer-dist
Creating a "laravel/laravel=9.3.7" project at "./%s"
Installing laravel/laravel (v9.3.7)
  - Downloading laravel/laravel (v9.3.7)
```